# V lookup formula to check if the value is blank then return blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulbNP.png)Please help me on the below vlookup function

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IFNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-" & StrcellltrCount & "],'[" & DestFileName & "]" & DSheet & "'!R2C1:R" & LastRowDest & "C2,2,FALSE),""No Category"")"

The above formula will give the following result
If value available then it will populate a column value, If value is blank the formula will populate '0' and IF the value not available then it will populate 'No Category'.

Here I need one small help , If the value is blank formula should update as blank instead of '0'

First Table                                 Second Table
Item Code    Des Category                  Item Code               Category
1006754      XXX                            1006754
1007882      XXX                            1007882
1009540      XXX                            1009540
1009559      XXX    A                       1009559                   A
1009575      XXX    E                       1009575                   E
1010824      XXX    B                       1010824                   B
1011413      XXX    C                       1011413                   C
1013459      XXX    D                       1013459                   D
1013491      XXX    No Category

First check whether Item code is available ,If available then check second table category column having value or not .if it is blank in second table then populate first table  category column as blank, If it is second table category column not blank then populate the with that value in first table and If the item is not available in second table populate that with 'No Category'
Many Thanks.

Comment: can you provide some sample data with expected output?

Comment: First Table     Second Table 
Item Code Description Category   Item Code Category
1006754 XXX    1006754 
1007882 XXX    1007882 
1009540 XXX    1009540 
1009559 XXX A   1009559 A
1009575 XXX E   1009575 E
1010824 XXX B   1010824 B
1011413 XXX C   1011413 C
1013459 XXX D   1013459 D
1013491 XXX No Category

Comment: Please see the image attached for the sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IF function like below i.e., when the result of VLOOKUP is 0 or an empty string.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(YOUR LOOKUP PARAMS) = "","")
```

Alternatively, you can use LEN or ISNUMBER function depending on your need.

```
=IF(LEN(VLOOKUP (PARAM))=0,"", VLOOKUP (PARAM))
```

Final answer,

```
=IF(
    ISNA(
    VLOOKUP(A11,F11:G18,2,FALSE)),"No Category",
    IF(VLOOKUP(A11,F11:G18,2,FALSE),"","")
    )
```

Comment: I am looking for Blanks not for Zero. Where ever blank value is there I have to keep that as blank. I am trying to include this case also in the same vlookup formula , Is that possible?

Comment: Since zero confuses you I just removed zero and replaced it with empty string. However, zero is just an example and you can compare whatever you want. Additionally, LEN can also be used based on the need. You cannot include this comparison in the VLOOKUP itself.

Comment: =IF(VLOOKUP(A11,F11:G18,2,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP(A11,F11:G18,2,FALSE)) with this I can handle both Blank and Value Available condition Only thing pending is If #N/A then populate 'No Category'. It will be great if you can help me with the function

Comment: This results an Error 'You have entered too many arguments for this function'

Comment: Still Same Issue

Comment: =IF(
ISNA(
VLOOKUP(A11,F11:G18,2,FALSE)),"No Category",
IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(A11,F11:G18,2,FALSE)) =0,"",
VLOOKUP(A11,F11:G18,2,FALSE)
))

Comment: You can also try this, =IF(
ISNA(
VLOOKUP(A11,F11:G18,2,FALSE)),"No Category",
IF(VLOOKUP(A11,F11:G18,2,FALSE),"","")
)

Comment: Last one is Working Fine .
Thanks a lot @govind ,

Comment: Added the last one to the answer and please mark it as answer & upvote it if that helps.

Comment: Yes, Sure. Thanks

Comment: One more small doubt , How to keep and pass that 'No category' as variable in the above formula.?

Comment: Please choose any row/column say A1 and set the value as "No category" and refer that in your function